# what is the common terms for different types of phones?

Tags: word-request

There are different kinds of phones, portables, fixes and among portables there are android/ios/windows phones smart as computers and other far more simple devices just with  function to call/answer. How they are called in common language? i especially look for name of simple non-smart gadgets.

Comment: I recently heard the term "button-phones". Is that close to what you need?

Comment: Actually, if you really want a list of all the different terms for all the different phones, then that seems too broad and likely off-topic for our format. I think it’s OK to focus on the “non-smart gadgets”, but if you have a specific example (description, picture, etc), that would be better. You can [edit] your post to include more details.

Comment: non-smart phone

Comment: thanks, for your answer it covers out all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say they are all *telephones*, or simply *phones*.

> #### [Telephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone#Digital_telephones_and_voice_over_IP)
>
> A telephone (derived from the Greek: τῆλε, tēle, "far" and φωνή, phōnē, "voice", together meaning "distant voice"), or phone, is a telecommunications device that permits two or more users to conduct a conversation when they are too far apart to be heard directly. A telephone converts sound, typically and most efficiently the human voice, into electronic signals that are transmitted via cables and other communication channels to another telephone which reproduces the sound to the receiving user.
>   (Wikipedia)

For the simple gadgets, I assume you mean cell phones that aren't "smart" (not the old rotary phones, for example). There are a few different terms out there, but I can't say which is the most popular. Here's a little snippet I found on [this site](https://theinformr.com/cell-phones/p/best-basic-phone-10094/), *Back to Basics: The Best Non-Smartphones*

> Whether you call them basic phones, dumb phones, feature phones, or non-smartphones, this guide is going to break down some of the best options available.

The only tip I can give at this moment is to avoid "dumb phones" if you want to be formal.

Comment: +1 for feature phone. That would refer to a phone that has stuff like a camera, bluetooth, media player, simple web browser, but is not actually a smartphone.
Probably with buttons, but those also exist with touch screens.

Comment: i had like write a question on security pro & cons for smartphones and especially feature phones. i will post question to security stackexchange community. if i do ...